# StringIO with BOM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, readline, stringio

I have a CSV file in memory that I've read using `ftp.getbinaryfile()` in `Net::FTP`.

I am using the `SmarterCSV` gem which requires a file or readline `StringIO` object.

I keep getting a BOM that appears in my row headers... and I'm trying to use StringIO to open it in 'bom' mode. Isn't it supposed to remove it if I do that?

So far I'm trying this below, but if I call `StringIO.new(csv_raw, 'r:bom|utf-8').read` the BOM is still there. How do I actually remove it?

```
  SmarterCSV.process(StringIO.new(csv_raw, 'r:bom|utf-8'), {
    headers_in_file: true,
    verbose: false
  })
```